# Segmentation fault in getc

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, strcmp, getc

Its just a program where i am trying to read the number of occurrences of the word passed as an argument in the file which is also passed as next argument.

Code looks like below :

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern void exit(int);

void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char C, buf[10];
    int count = 0, i = 0;
    FILE *fp;

    if ( argc != 3 ) {
        printf("Please provide proper args\n");
        exit(0);
    } 
    fp = fopen(argv[2], "r");
    if( fp == NULL ) {
        printf("File couldn't be opened\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    else {
           do { 
               while ( (C = fgetc(fp)) && ( C != ' ')  ) {
                  //if ( C  == EOF ) break; 
                  buf[i] = C;
                  i++;
               }
           buf[i] = '\0';
               i = 0;

               if (strcmp(argv[1], buf) == 0) count++; 
           } while (C != EOF );
     } 
     close(fp);
     printf("Total \"%s\" occurances is %d\n", argv[1], count);

}
```

GDB :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00007ffff7a925fd in getc () from /lib64/libc.so.6
Missing separate debuginfos, use: debuginfo-install glibc-2.18-12.fc20.x86_64
```

Now it will not segfault if i remove the comment before the `"if"` statement after the first `while`. The only line in this program is commented.

But if that is the case then we have definitely crossed the `getc` part and entered into the while. I was thinking that the problem could be while doing the `strcmp`. But why do i see the error in `getc` in gdb.

Comment: If `fgetc` returns `EOF`, you should not read more, doing so will result in undefined behavior. What you do when you don't check for `EOF` is attempting to read beyond the end of the file.

Comment: Also note that `C` needs to be `int`, not `char`, if you want to be able to reliably test for `EOF`.

Comment: But then it doesn't crash if i uncomment "//if ( C  == EOF ) break;"

Comment: And i beileve i am not reading beyond EOF which is being controlled by the outer do while loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the check for end of file outcommented you actually have an infinite loop, where [`fgetc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc)  continues to return `EOF` but you never check for it. This leads to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) because you will then write well beyond the bounds of the `buf` array. What probably happens is that you then overwrite the `FILE` pointer `fp`, casing the next call to `fgetc` to operate on an invalid `FILE` pointer.

Also as noted in another comment, [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgetc) returns an `int`. You need to know that `(char) EOF != (int) EOF`.

Comment: But i have another do while (outer loop) after that which won't lead us to read beyond the EOF.

Comment: @kingsdeb But the inner loop is infinite, it doesn't matter if you have a check in the outer loop as the inner loop will never exit.

Comment: Thanks i got your point. I wasn't thinking on those line at all.